# The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, linq-to-entities

I have this code inside my edmx designer file:

```
    #region Navigation Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("EnviroModel", "FK_Whiteout_Field1", "Field")]
    public Field Field
    {
        get
        {
            **return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<Field>("EnviroModel.FK_Whiteout_Field1", "Field").Value;**
        }
        set
        {
            ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<Field>("EnviroModel.FK_Whiteout_Field1", "Field").Value = value;
        }
    }
```

I am getting following error in get part:

```
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
```

Comment: Is a Field property eagerly loaded?

Comment: @ Ladislav Mrnka  how can I determine if it is eagerly loaded ?